# Finotes version upgrade is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am using an iOS framework called *fi.notes*. Currently i am using the version 2.1.0. I tried to update to 2.3.1. But i keep getting the error in terminal, when i run pod install

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `FinotesCore (= 2.3.1)` required by `Podfile`
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `FinotesCore (= 2.3.1)`.
I am following their developer documentation, which can be found here

> https://finotes.github.io/2018/02/02/objc-docs

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you update your pod repo first?
try pod install --repo-update, as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed adding --repo-update in pod install
pod install --repo-update
Please make sure the version in Podfile is the latest one, and re-run the pod install command.

Good luck building better apps with *fi.notes.* :)